# Continuous Probability

Tags: probability

The lifetime of a machine part has a continuous distribution on the interval
(0, 40) with probability density function f, where f(x) is proportional to
(10 + x)^(−2).
Calculate the probability that the lifetime of the machine part is less than 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

You'll need your probability density function to have total integral 1:

$$
\int_0^{40}f(x)dx=1
$$  So, you'll have to find the right constant to stick in front of $(10+x)^{-2}$.

Then, to calculate the probability that the lifetime is less than 6, you simply integrate $f(x)$ from 0 to 6.

Comment: Oh wow! So that was what proportional meant. Thanks!

Comment: Yep, any time we say "$f(x)$ is proportional to $g(x)$" we just mean $f(x)=Cg(x)$ for some constant $C$.